# USB driver for RCA 7 Voyager rct6773W22

Tags: adb, usb-drivers

I can't seem to get my RCA rct6773W22 (7 Voyager) tablet to be detected via USB and RCA does not offer any driver.

If anyone has any idea how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same tablet and have been unable to find a way for this to work. I don't see a platform listed in the question or tags - Linux, Windows, Mac? I can't get it working in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on this [website](http://ryancuda.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-get-working-adb-drivers-for.html). I will briefly summarize the steps I took to allow my RCA Voyager (RCT6873W42) running Marshmallow 6.0 to sync up with my Windows 7 computer and ADB in Android Studio.

1. Install the [Google USB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html).
2. Find the device ID by navigating in Windows to Control Panel > Device Manager > Other Devices > Android ADB Interface > right-click: Properties > tab: Details > ‘Property’ drop-down: Hardware Ids, which yielded

   - `USB\VID_8087&PID_0928&REV_FFFF&MI_01`
   - `USB\VID_8087&PID_0928&MI_01`
3. Open up `C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf` in Notepad++ and add the following lines after both `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]`

   ```
   ;RCA Tablet RCT6873W42
   %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_8087&PID_0928&REV_FFFF&MI_01
   %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_8087&PID_0928&MI_01
   ```

   (Notice that you have appended the device IDs you obtained in step 2 to the direction `%SingleAdbInterface%=USB_Install,`.)
4. After saving `android_winusb.inf`, navigate back to the device manager, right-click on the unknown device (Android ADB Interface) and choose ‘Update Driver Software…’.
5. Choose Browse my computer for driver software: Locate and install driver software manually. Then choose Browse, navigating to where the drivers are stored (`C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`) and clicking OK.
6. Make sure that the ‘Include subfolders’ option is checked and click Next.
7. If you open up Android Studio with your device connected, it should now show up in the ADB after several seconds.

**Note:** Some of these details may vary. The location of your SDK will undoubtedly be different. What you write in the `.inf` file comment is arbitrary. I chose to write `;RCA Tablet RCT6873W42`. I assume you have enabled developer options on your device, allowing USB. You should be able to easily follow Google's direction on installing their USB drivers. An additional step was listed on the website (see above) which I did not have to follow.

Answer (score 0):

This device works with the [standard Google USB Drivers](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip). But some sources say that the driver info file has to be modified before installing.

From an [XDA Topic on the RCA Voyager 7 Tablet](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=57100493&postcount=112):

> Download/unzip the latest Android USB drivers from Google then add:
>
> ```
> ;RCA Tablet
> %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0414&PID_0C02&REV_0216&MI_01
> %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0414&PID_0C02&MI_01
> ```
>
> after the `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]` in `android_winusb.inf` file

The driver is available in the SDK Manager tool or as a [standalone download](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip).

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something you may want to try, set the USB connection to use the PTP protocol rather than MTP. I did not need to modify any drivers, my RCT6773W22B was recognized as 'a camera.

Modern Android devices use the MTP or PTP protocols — you can choose which one you prefer.

To select a USB connection protocol, open the Settings app, tap Storage, tap the menu button, and tap USB computer connection. You’ll also see the protocol your device is using as a notification when it’s connected to a computer via USB.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it kept giving me an unable to install driver, so I selected update device driver, browse computer, then let me pick, click Google, Inc., Android ADB Interface, click next, click ok when it says may not be compatible, and then it showed up on my listed devices

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the changes in the .inf file and
enabling Developer on the RCA Voyager tablet, I had to enable USB debugging.
Once you enable Developer mode.
You'll see Developer Options in the Settings menu.
Under Debugging you can turn on USB debugging